# Branching conversation in Amazon Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Is there a way to branch a conversation depending on a user input on an intent?

For example: Consider a binary intent such as "isRent" with an utterance "Are you renting right now?". The user is likely to answer either "yes" or "no". At this point, I have some more slots to ask the user. How do I update the prompt to ask for slots after this depending on the user's answer?

isRent

- yes - What is your monthly rent? (collecting a value for slot {payment})
- no  - What is your monthly mortgage payment? (collecting the value for same slot as above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Lambda function to handle `Initialization and validation code hook` and do the branching in here.

The `make-appointment` example blueprint has some good hints for how to rephrase a question based on previous responses.

As an aside, I've noticed that AWS Lex has trouble with yes/no questions so you may need to rephrase your question to get around this problem. (Also, if you find the solution to this please answer the unanswered SO questions about this)

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer provides very good details that helped me branch my conversation flow. I would like to add specifically that this particular part of documentation is helpful: [ElicitSlot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html).

Using ElicitSlot can effectively ask for a specific slot and replace the prompt that you define on the GUI console. This can be combined with a state management (having a state session attributes in my case) to know when to switch state.